# Output of a module used as input of another in verilog

Tags: input, module, output, verilog

While inside a module A I'm trying to use the output of a module B as the input of another module C. Essentially this is a "go" switch that is flipped in module B after certain conditions are met and then this is supposed to be the trigger for module C to activate. Is it possible to link an output and input like this?

I've been reading around and found [this image](http://www.asic-world.com/images/verilog/ports.gif) particularly helpful - however, I don't quite understand the concept of nets or if they will be helpful. Would wiring the output of module B to a reg that's used as input to module C work? Thanks.

EDIT:

I'm looking for something like [this](http://puu.sh/4NL3O.png) (involving 3 different modules) where I'm instantiating a module B and a module C within a module A. I want to connect B's output to C's input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make those connections
For example:

```
module my_moduleA (inA, outA)
input inA;
output reg outA; //If you want to assign something to out inside an always block, it has to be output reg, otherwise you will have to use assign out from an always block.

//Put your logic here

endmodule

module my_moduleB (inB, outB)
input inB;
output reg outB; //If you want to assign something to out inside an always block, it has to be output reg, otherwise you will have to use assign out from an always block.

//Put your logic here

//Instantiation of module A
my_moduleA instance(  //Here is the connection made between module A and B
.inA (inB),  
.outA (outB));
endmodule
```

This is how the connections are made, if you want to make those connections on internal signals, then you can use wire type

Comment: I just edited my post with more clarification. Does your response apply to what I'm looking for?

Comment: Yes it does, just in that case i recommend you to use wires in module A to make connections .

Comment: Lets say I have made a module of full adder. Now to change it into 4 bit full adder how can i use the `cout` from instance of FA1 as `cin` into FA2

Answer (score 4):

Your three modules example ([image](http://puu.sh/4NL3O.png)), using wire outB_to_inC to connect output to input:

```
//A.v
module A(inA, outA);
input wire inA;
output wire outA;

wire outB_to_inC;

B B_inst(.inB(inA), .outB(outB_to_inC));

C C_inst(.inC(outB_to_inC), .outC(outA));

endmodule

/////

//B.v
module B (inB, outB);
input wire inB;
output wire outB;

//... more code here

endmodule

/////

//C.v
module C (inC, outC);
input wire inC;
output wire outC;

//... more code here

endmodule
```

---