# How to link output of a module to the input of another in System Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Im not quite sure how to make a module which allows the output(B) of one module to become the input of another module(C).

Comment: It seems the OP already understands that modules have inputs and outputs. But not understanding how modules get instantiated and connections (the flow of assignments/drivers to sources) made is a very broad topic in SystemVerilog.

Comment: Duplicate of [Output of a module used as input of another in verilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327819/output-of-a-module-used-as-input-of-another-in-verilog?rq=1)?

Answer (score 2):

1) you need to declare your modules with input and output ports

```
 module A(input clk, input sig, output out);
          .. do somethign here
 endmodule

 module B(input clk, output val);
         ... do something to generate val.
 endmodule
```

2) you would need to create a hierarchy of instances, instantiating those modules, inside a top-level one. The latter will declare wires which should be used to connect these two:

```
module top(output topout);
  wire clk;
  wire sig;
  wire out;

  A a(clk, sig, topout);
  B b(clk, sig);
endmodule
```

So, in the above example output port `val` of instance `b` of module `B` is assigned to the wire `sig` of the top-level module. The same wire `sig` is connected to the input port `sig` of the instance `a` of the module `A`.

The output port `out` of the insance `a` is also connected to the output port `topout` port of the top-level module.

in both cases the `clk` wire is connected to two input ports: instance `a` and instance `b`.

This is the basic idea.